# Don't know about flushed view UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

recently i am getting a crash on firebase regarding `UIPageViewController`

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Don't know about flushed view <UIView: 0x14c5379a0; frame = (0 0; 384 152.333); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280c57f60>; layer = <CALayer: 0x280188fe0>>
-[CFPrefsSearchListSource addManagedSourceForIdentifier:user:]



Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1abb00878 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c0056c50 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1aba06000 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource addManagedSourceForIdentifier:user:]
3  Foundation                     0x1acd9791c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x1adcebfc4 -[UIPageViewController _flushViewController:animated:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1adcec07c -[UIPageViewController queuingScrollView:didFlushView:animated:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x1adcf3110 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _flushView:animated:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x1adcf3298 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _replaceViews:updatingContents:adjustContentInsets:animated:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x1adcf655c -[_UIQueuingScrollView _didScrollWithAnimation:force:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x1adcf25e4 -[_UIQueuingScrollView layoutSubviews]
10 UIKitCore                      0x1ae9fbd90 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
11 QuartzCore                     0x1aef11384 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
12 QuartzCore                     0x1aef11858 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
13 QuartzCore                     0x1aef25ff8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
14 QuartzCore                     0x1aee6bee0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
15 QuartzCore                     0x1aee9736c CA::Transaction::commit()
16 QuartzCore                     0x1aee986fc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1aba7b358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1aba755c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1aba75b74 __CFRunLoopRun
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1aba7521c CFRunLoopRunSpecific
21 GraphicsServices               0x1c2af4784 GSEventRunModal
22 UIKitCore                      0x1ae4ae200 -[UIApplication _run]
23 UIKitCore                      0x1ae4b3a74 UIApplicationMain
25 libdyld.dylib                  0x1ab7356c0 start
```

and in my code i am using it like this :

```
      DispatchQueue.main.async{
            
            self.pc.numberOfPages = self.pages.count
                
            
            self.pageContainer.setViewControllers([self.pages[0]],
                                                  direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward,
                                                  animated: false,
                                                  completion: nil)
            
            self.view_controllerHolder.addSubview(self.pageContainer.view)
            
            
            self.pageContainer.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.pageContainer.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pageContainer.view.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            self.pageContainer.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pageContainer.view.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            self.pageContainer.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pageContainer.view.superview!.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            self.pageContainer.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pageContainer.view.superview!.heightAnchor).isActive = true
            
            self.pageContainer.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }


///DELEGATE PAGER
extension vc_landing:UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate  {
    
 
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
  
        let currentIndex = pages.firstIndex(of:viewController)
        if currentIndex == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex! - 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
 
        let currentIndex = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController)
        if currentIndex == pages.count-1 {
            return nil
        }
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex! + 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
 
         pendingIndex = pages.firstIndex(of:pendingViewControllers.first!)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
   
        if completed {
            
            currentIndex = pendingIndex
            if let index = currentIndex {
                self.autoScroll = 0
                self.pc.currentPage = index
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

i am not sure how to catch this error on my device simulating.

Comment: Did you get it fixed? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Nope , i had to remove the animations inside one of the views and its worked , i am not sure what was the problem

Comment: Facing same issue mainly iOS 12

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Same thing, iOS 16.2